# Окончания -ы или -ой в существительных женского рода (страны-страной)

Tags: падежи

Во фразах типа... Участвую в управлении страны или в управлении страной?
Ведь вопрос будет - в управлении ЧЕГО и тогда это род. падеж. Но тогда будет и окончание -ы. Т.е. страны. Но ведь фактически принято говорить не так, а страной (будто бы это творительный падеж... в управлении чем?). Необязательно страны... можно школы и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

*Состоять в управлении железной дороги.* || "Участвовать" в таких случаях плохо подходит, звучит как принимать участие, но не работать официально.
Словарное значение: *административное учреждение или административный орган внутри какого-либо учреждения*. Здесь не подходит творительный падеж.

*Участвовать в управлении школой.*
Словарное значение: *процесс действия по глаголу "управлять"*. Здесь не подходит родительный падеж.

Примечание: не всякий руководящий орган можно назвать управлением, школы для этого маловато, а страны многовато (страной управляют несколько органов власти, а не один).

Примечание 2: обычно эти органы так и называются: *управление [чего-то там].*

Примечание 3: говорят не "*управление школы*", а "*руководство школы*".

Примечание 4: во фразе "*перейдут под управление школы*" смысл в том, что школа будет управлять этим, поэтому родительный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

Падеж зависимого слова определяется значением слова *управление*. Если слово *управление* в значении «*регулирование хода*, *движения*, *работы чего-нибудь*», то зависимое слово в тв. п.: управление (чем?) — управление атомобилем; управление имением; управление системными проектами (регулирование их хода, движения).

Словарь трудностей | Управление

new.gramota.ru›trudnosti

(В отличие от *управления* как структурного подразделения в организации. Пример: «Управление сельского хозяйства Минобороны России»).

Comment: УправлениЕ (чем?) школОЙ - это само собой ясно (твор. падеж). Вопрос был про другое. Когда мы говорим участвие в управлениИ... Вот тут то мне и неясно! Тут по моей логике ставится вопрос ни чем, а чего и тогда это родительный и соответствующее окончание.

Comment: Ваш Вопрос был об управлении страной или страны, т.е. зависимого слова? Нет разницы в каком падеже слово главное. Важно лишь его значение в конкретном контексте. Правильно: управление страной (управление процессами жизнедеятельности страны).